# my comment_form() wont display the form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to render a default form in wordpress using comment_form() but it just wont display the html form content. I have put comment_form in comments.php and also in my custom single post type. it will load in the default single.php though.

I added support for comments to my custom product type in my functions.php via:

```
add_post_type_support( 'product', array( 'comments' ) );
```

Still the comment_form wont display, although I have had no problem displaying the comments, just the comment_form wont work.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Surely by adding in just `<?php comments_template(); ?>` should be enough to show the default comments template?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that I tried it already, doesnt work. The comments display no problem, but the form doesnt it. Would it make a difference if I used a callback on: wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'product_reviews', 'style' => 'ol' ) ); in my comments.php  I have been using this for a while and calls the comments fine, but just checking it would affect the comment_form() at the bottom of comments.php

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that my problem was custom post type was not set in the admin to allow comments. checking that checkbox fixed the issue.